# Value comparison doesn't return results

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, bitmap

So I have a class that takes 2 numbers. A start number and end number and then compares the values from the start number to the end number with images that are saved in a `Dictionary<String, Bitmap>` and saves the matched images to another `Bitmap` array for it to be printed.
eg you input the number 1 as a starting number and the number 5 as the end.
The program will then create an `int` array that holds the values from 1 to 5. ie 1,2,3,4,5. this array is then converted to a `String` array and is formatted to 5 digits as the numbers must be in that format when printed. 00001,00002,00003,00004,00005. For the comparison however the numbers must be single values so I append the whole string array into one single `string` and then into  a `Char[]` for the comparison. 
This is the class that looks after this whole process.

```
private Bitmap[] Process()
{
    //Main variables
    int min = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int max = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    List<int> fullVal = new List<int>();
    Boolean converted = false;
    int i;
    //adds the starting number to the array and then increments it by one each time.
    for (int count = 0; count < max;count++)
    {
        fullVal.Add(min);
        min++;
    }

    //converts the new int list to a string array formatted to 5 digits.
    String[] values = new String[fullVal.Count];
    for (int count = 0; count < max;count++)
    {
        values[count] = fullVal[count].ToString("00000");
    }
    //transforms string array into a single string to be converted to char array.
    String complete = null;
    for (int count = 0; count < max; count++)
    {
        complete += values[count];
    }

    //converts string into char array for comparison.
    Char[] indVals = complete.ToCharArray();

    //Dictionary of bitmap images and their respective names.
    Dictionary<String, Bitmap> namesAndImages = new Dictionary<String, Bitmap>();

    var resourceManager = Resource1.ResourceManager;
    var resources = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

    foreach (DictionaryEntry myResource in resources)
    {
        if (myResource.Value is Bitmap) //is this resource is associated with an image
        {
            String resName = myResource.Key.ToString(); //get resource's name

            Bitmap resImage = myResource.Value as Bitmap; //get the Image itself

            namesAndImages.Add(resName, resImage);
        }
    }
    //COMPARISON!! Creates bitmap array to hold the matched images. In this case it holds every image in a sequence
    //for it to be sent to the printer class and printed 5 per page.
    Bitmap[] compare = new Bitmap[values.Length];//array that holds the matched images from pics[]

    while (converted == false)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            if (namesAndImages.Keys.ElementAt(i).ToCharArray().Contains(indVals[i]))
            {
                compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_0"]);
            }
            else
            {
                switch (indVals[i])
                {
                    case '1': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_1"]);
                        break;
                    case '2': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_2"]);
                        break;
                    case '3': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_3"]);
                        break;
                    case '4': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_4"]);
                        break;
                    case '5': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_5"]);
                        break;
                    case '6': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_6"]);
                        break;
                    case '7': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_7"]);
                        break;
                    case '8': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_8"]);
                        break;
                    case '9': compare[i] = new Bitmap(namesAndImages["_9"]);
                        break;

                    default: break;


                }
            }
        }
        converted = true;
    }
    return compare;
}
```

When I call the process class and assign the call to a bitmap array the array is empty. I cant work out where I'm going wrong with the comparison or the bitmap assignment.

Comment: You can't "call a class". Please show us what you *are* doing with the class. Are you just calling `Process()`? What you should do is put a breakpoint on the first line of your `Process()` method, run the program, and step through the code with F10. You'll find out what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Try performing some debugging. Use break points or some sort of output for each step. You have one method that does like 5 things. Maybe split it up and test each part. Obviously your bitmap assigning will fail if your resource lookup fails or if the numbers aren't assigned correctly (I already see a problem when you put values into "fullVal").

Also, use parameters.

Comment: Your loops are all assuming that `min` is 1.  You should be doing `for(int num = min; num <= max; num++) { fullVal.Add(num) }` and all other loops should be done for the actual size for the list you are iterating like `for(int count = 0; count < fullVal.Count; count++)`.

Comment: Also for creating one `string` from an array or list of strings you can use `string.Join` or `string.Concat`.

Comment: Finally you're doing a loop from 0 to `max` but then using it in char array which makes absolutely no sense at all since there will be many more characters in the zero filled concatenated string than `max`.

Comment: Okay so I took your advise Ed and have found that when the program gets to the comparison is isnt doing the bitmap assignment. It jumps straight from the if statement into the switch and then straight to the default in the switch without checking any of the elements in the 'Char[]' array.

Comment: @MacMan Ok, now use the watch window in the debugger to examine the values of the variables and find out *why* it does that.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks Ed that was a great help. I'm was mainly a java programmer up until recently so I didnt know about break points and using F10 in visual studio. Has helped me identify the problems and it now seems to be working. I will let you know if it all goes to plan.